# when running the below python script, it is first saving all the shell command output and later it is saving the print message output in the file.

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
f = open("output.txt", "w")
print>>f, "/etc/hosts output:\n"
print>>f, "____________________\n"
subprocess.call('cat /etc/hosts',stdout=f,shell=True)
print>>f, "hostname output:\n"
print>>f, "____________________"
subprocess.call('hostname',stdout=f,shell=True)
```

and the below is the output.txt file....

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain

node1.example.com

/etc/hosts output:
```

---

```
hostname output:
```

---

We need this output.txt in this format as below....

```
/etc/hosts output:
 ____________________
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain


hostname output:
____________________

node1.example.com
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `f.flush()` just before each `suboprocess.call` help? Also instead of `print>>f, "/etc/hosts output:\n"` you could `f.write("/etc/hosts output:\n")`.

Comment: As a note, I don't know why _Python_ is involved, since it looks like a _shell_ style approach: the code looks seems to be written by a sys admin rather than a programmer (e.g. using `subprocess.call("cat,...` instead of `open`/`readlines`).

Answer (score 0):

Subprocesses will work asyncronsly with the application, that is why this behaviour, however you can also do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
f = open("output.txt", "w")
#print>>f, "/etc/hosts output:\n"
#print>>f, "____________________\n"
subprocess.call('echo "/etc/hosts output:" \n echo "____________________" \n cat /etc/hosts',stdout=f,shell=True)
#print>>f, "hostname output:\n"
#print>>f, "____________________"
subprocess.call('echo "hostname output:" \n  echo "____________________" \n hostname',stdout=f,shell=True)
```